# Correlating `docker ps` with host's `ps`

Tags: linux, docker

`docker ps` does not let me know the pid of the container itself. Doing command string matching between the outputs of `docker ps` and `ps` run on the host is not foolproof since I can have the same command run on the host.

Does anyone have a sure way of correlating the two?

Comment: Personally, I would consider using sysdig on the host to run queries about the status of containers. That way you can ask for `proc.vpid` to get the PID as seen from inside the process's own namespace, or `proc.pid` to get the global one.

Comment: Why you want to get the PID of the container process?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Why not?

Comment: I meant to understand the usecase

Comment: @TarunLalwani The use case is in the question itself. I need it for correlation. I need to correlate the container ID to the PID(s) it holds on the host for zillions of uses i have not thought of yet. The question is not dependent on a use case and is a generic one. I need a way that is sureshot and not something that can have ambiguity(like the method I am using now).

Comment: Why not use `docker inspect -f "{{ .State.Pid }}" containerid` to get the PID?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Wow! that works, but not completely. In the sense that, if that process spawned child processes, it doesn't show that here. Those child processes exist in the container as well as the host. But I think I can solve that using a pgrep after i get the parent process from your command. Please list it as an answer and if you have a better command to address what I just said, even better. I'll accept it. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the container's PID use below

```
$ CPID=$(docker inspect -f "{{ .State.Pid }}" $containerid)
```

To get all the child processes of the above process, use

```
$ pgrep -P $CPID
```